# Система авторизации на php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Имеется интернет магазин с системой авторизации.В БД у каждого пользователя имеется email и passord.На сайте пользователь вводит свой email и пароль, после чего просходить проверка существования такого пользователя.Если пользователь существует, то в скрипте происходит внедрение на компьютер пользователя двух cookie файлов, в которых содержится значение email и password из БД в зашифрованном виде.Далаа на главной странице происходит проверка существования cookie, если они существуют, то пользователь считается авторизованным, т.е на сайте вместо блока со ссылкой "войти" появляется email, сохраненный в cookie с названием email.В разделе корзина происходит подключение к БД, email и password берутся из cookie, далее при успешном подключении выводятся товары, которые пользователь положил в корзину.Как думаете, это хорошая система авторизации?Или можно сделать лучше?

Comment: Не надо хранить в куках пароль. В php имеется готовый механизм сессий https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php начинаете сессию session_start() и все нужные для работы пользователя данных сохраняете в $_SESSION.

Comment: Если стандартные сессии не подходят то лучше сделать что то свое боле менее похожее на него. в куках вполне можно хранить логин. Но вместо пароля, хоть и шифрованного лучше хранить некую случайную информацию, которая будет меняться от сессии к сессии и хранится где то на сервере. Если вы храните пароль, то кража таких кук позволит входить на сайт вплоть до изменения пароля. У вас не будет способа запретить вход какой то конкретной сессии, не поменяв пароль и не отрубив при этом все остальные сессии пользователя